# Is there a way to specify a custom root path for `file://` protocol html pages?

Tags: html

I have a page that I want to run serverless (using the file protocol) as well as in a server. But I need to absolute paths in my html for the server, and that means that the html file opened up using the `file://` protocol will look at the root of my harddrive. It would be ideal if there was some kind of meta tag I could give to change the root like this:

```
<meta root="C://whatever/whatever">
```

or even

```
<meta root="current-directory">
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you probably want to use root-relative paths `/path/to/wherever`, and locally use a custom domain by adding a hosts entry so that your local testing is on a local server along the lines of `http://yoursite.local`

Comment: It looks like [the `<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) might do what you're looking for.

Comment: @zzzzBov Wouldn't that require me to be running a webserver? Also, it would require everyone who wants to access this file to modify their hosts file. That's exactly the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @timolawl Good idea, but looks like that only works for relative URLs. I could use relative urls and specify <base> only on my server side, but I'm worried about interactions with an application that's being run side by side with this html

Comment: @BT I don't understand why the <base> tag doesn't work in your situation it seems to be exactly what you describe.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride My issue is that I have a static html page that I copy most of the parts from to a server-hosted application. I don't want that base url used in the server-hosted application but I do want my static html page to run by opening locally (for ease of development). The basic problem is that my setup is janky